# Django is not sending e-mails

Tags: django, smtp, sendmail

guys!

I have an issue with my Django project.

About project:

```
Django version: 3.0.7
Django hosting provider: Digitalocean
E-mail hosting provider: Beget.com
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6
```

Here is my **settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.beget.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MyVerySecretPassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='my@email.com'
```

Here is my **views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Please, activate your account by clicking the link below.'
        message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')

        send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [to_email])
```

What I have tried to solve my problem:

1. Using gmail account (yes, with anabled 'Allow less secure apps')
2. Sending via Django shell (nope, it returns code '1', the mailbox is as empty as my ideas:( )
3. I have opened 587 and 465 ports in ufw
4. I tried to write and run simple python smtp script to send e-mail via Django shell (spoiler: it worked perfectly on my server via shell), but when I tried to implement this code into my Django code, it failed just like Django send_mail() function:

here is the code:

```
import smtplib

def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):


    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if isinstance(recipient, list) else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    print(message)
    try:
        server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.beget.com", 465)
        server_ssl.ehlo()
        server_ssl.login(user, pwd)
        server_ssl.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server_ssl.close()
        print('successfully sent the mail')

    except:
        print("failed to send mail")

usn='sender@email.com'
pwd='MyVerySecretPassword'
rc=['reciever@email.com']
subj='HoHoHo'
body='Hello, world'

send_email(usn,pwd,rc,subj,body)
```

5. I checked all the variables (rendered them on the screen) which I tried to send via e-mail, all of them are correct.
6. Sorry, I am not interested in third party projects like Sendgrid. I just want to understand what I am doing wrong.

Hope someone could help me to find the bug. Thank you very much!

Comment: If `send_mail` isn't failing with any exceptions, and returns `1`, then it means it successfully delivered the mail to your SMTP server. You'd need to check the SMTP server logs to see what it is doing with the message. It is possible the message is being marked as spam or quarantined because of SPF/DMARC policies on the sender domain. I don't think there is a bug in your implementation - it's simply a deliverability issue with your SMTP server.

Comment: (Checking for spam/quarantine would have to be on the receiving server).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Thank to **Solarissmoke** for answering to my question.

The real thing was in fact that my hosting provider blocked outgoing traffic. So the best solution is to user third-party mail delivery provider like Google or Sendinblue. After I changed my settings, everything worked.
Hope my post could help anyone.

Answer (score -1):

It works with settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.beget.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "your email"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "your password"
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```